# Java: Access the right map depending on variable without using "if"

Tags: java

so that's my situation:

I have a method which gets a String and a bunch of other information.
Depending on the content of the String, I want to put the other information into one of two Maps I have. Like this:

```
if (string.equals("A")) {
  A.put[..]
} else if (string.equals("B")) {
  B.put[..]
}
```

but because this situation happens a few times in my method, I don't want to use if/else every time because of redundancy.

Soo I guess what I need is some kind of object/pointer/reference which I can assign the Map I want to use *once* in the beginning and then use it as a placeholder.

Comment: So ... you want a conditional statement, without an actual conditional statement? ....

Comment: if it happens only a few times, you'd better leave the things as is.

Comment: @Stultuske I want less conditional statements, not noone. Which I realized using ctsts answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why we have reference variables:

```
Map<?,?> map;
if(string.equals("A"))
    map = A;
else if(string.equals("B"))
    map = B;
else
    map = new HashMap<>();
```

works fine. The last line is more like an error-check for your String and will be garbage collected after your method is finished (otherwise map might not be initialised, which would throw a NullPointer). After this you can put everything into map (thank reference variables :-) ). Remember map is just a reference to your Map A or B (or "void")

Comment: Wow, I've been writing stuff in Java for 3 years and didn't know that. Shame on me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want a Map of Maps.

```
Map<String, Map<?, ?>> maps = new HashMap<>();

Map<?, ?> map = map.get(string);
map.put[...];
```

if you want to add the map as required you can use

```
Map<?, ?> map = map.computeIfAbsent(string, HashMap::new);
```